# Integrating MAPKIT and adding a accessibility arrow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/mapkit-example-in-iphone/) that guided me to add `MAPKIT` to my application and to display some data on the map as shown [in this image](http://www.silverlightshow.net/Storage/Users/KotanCode/__image_thumb.png).

I need to get the `Blue color arrow` (accessibility control) on the map description. My code is as follows, how do i add the blue color accessibility arrow on to it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
    region.center.latitude = 22.569722 ;
    region.center.longitude = 88.369722;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

    [mapView setDelegate:self];

    DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
    ann.title = @" Kolkata";
    ann.subtitle = @"Mahatma Gandhi Road"; 
    ann.coordinate = region.center; 
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
}
```

The full code can be found in the tutorial.

And also how do i edit the code to add a Customized image, instead of the default Red pin ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the blue arrow in mapView:viewForAnnotation:

```
pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```